# change checkbox listitem bij clicking a button

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm working on application where I want to change listitem through some buttons fields in a SharePoint. alone I keep getting an error when compiling the query,

I would like that when I press the button "hidekfinal_click" that a checkbox in the field "disabled" will be checkt

when i debug the code i see that it will collect notting from the query that I have formulated

can anyone help me, my code is:

> btn = new Button();
>               btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.hidekfinal_click);

```
        btn.Text = "1verberg kwart finale";
        btn.CssClass = "ms-ButtonHeightWidth";
        btn.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
        cell.Controls.Add(btn);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
```

> void hidekfinal_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>           {

```
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
        SPList list = web.Lists["wedstrijden"];

        SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();

        oQuery.Query = ("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Disabled' /></Value></Eq></Where>");

        SPListItemCollection collListItems = list.GetItems(oQuery);
        foreach (SPListItem item in collListItems)
        {
            item["Disabled"] = true;
            item.Update();


            bool enabled = true;
            if (item["Disabled"] != null)
                enabled = !(bool)item["Disabled"];
            item.Update();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CAML query is invalid this is probably why it is not returning any values. You must specify a value in the `<Value>` tag. It should look something like

```
<Where>
   <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="Disabled" />
      <Value Type="Boolean">1</Value>
   </Eq>
</Where>
```